# How do I create a dynamic where clause using a List in LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

```
 var query_loc = (from at in db.amenities_types
                     join a in db.amenities on at.id equals a.amenities_type
                     join u in db.unitInfos on a.unit_id equals u.id
                     join l in db.locations on u.locations_id equals l.id
                     join o in db.organizations on l.organization_id equals o.id
                     join ot in db.organization_types on o.id equals ot.organization_id
                     where (((u.price >= low_rent) && (u.price <= high_rent)) 
                              || (u.price == null))
                     && (u.bedrooms <= beds) && (u.bathrooms <= baths)
                     && amenities_list.Contains(at.id)
                     && (((ot.active == true) && (DateTime.Now <= ot.deactivateDate))
                          || ((ot.active == true) && (ot.deactivateDate == null)))
                         && (((l.active == true) && (DateTime.Now <= l.deactivateDate))
                          || ((l.active == true) && (l.deactivateDate == null)) )
                     && (ot.type == 8)
                     orderby o.name ascending, l.name ascending
                     select new { l, o, u, ot, at });
```

The specific line I need to replace is

where
amenities_list.Contains(at.id)

Instead it needs to produce SQL like this ([at.id] = 29 AND [at.id] = 30 AND [at.id] = 40)

So how do I get my List to produce the above SQL code in LINQ to SQL.

Comment: `([at.id] = 29 AND [at.id] = 30 AND [at.id] = 40)` would always be false. Do you mean `[at.id] IN (29, 30, 40)`?

Comment: is it something like this?

int[] list = { 1, 2, 3 }

then

where at.id in list?

Comment: you could always download the extended linq library (called dynamic linq if im not way off) where you can actually type real sql strings into linq methods like .where(), you could do something like .where("col LIKE '%something%') or .orderby("col ASC"); think you can find it through scott gu's blog

Comment: if the amenities_list is a variable of type List<int>, that should work!  what is the type of the variable (not instance type).

Comment: yes I did mean OR, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create methods for your clauses, you are scaring me.

```
var query_loc = (from at in db.amenities_types 
                 join a in db.amenities on at.id equals a.amenities_type 
                 join u in db.unitInfos on a.unit_id equals u.id 
                 join l in db.locations on u.locations_id equals l.id 
                 join o in db.organizations on l.organization_id equals o.id 
                 join ot in db.organization_types on o.id equals ot.organization_id 
                 where
                    PriceIsValid(u)
                 && BedsAndBathsArevalid(u) 
                 && AtIdIsValid(at.id)
                 && SomeCrazyDateConditionIsValid(ot, l)
                 && TheOtTypeIsValid(ot)
                 orderby o.name ascending, l.name ascending 
                 select new { l, o, u, ot, at });
```

And if you mean at.is = 29 OR at.id = 30 OR at.id = 40, then use an AtIdIsValid(at.id) predicate like:

```
bool AtIdIsValid(int atId){ return (atId == 29 || atId == 30 || atId == 40); }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help people.  I'm still used to writing SQL, this information has helped a great deal.

Comment: It's linq-to-sql, this won't work. Linq-to-sql can't translate custom methods to SQL

Comment: jeroenh is right, you cant use custom functions in linq. OP did you get his code to work before marking as answer?

Comment: you are right after trying this out i wasn't able to actually get it to work.  i ended up solving my problems with a left outer join.  i went a different route.